# Nuxt: i18n.localePath access in middleware

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

I've defined a namespaced middleware for Nuxt like so:

```
export default function({ store, redirect, app }){
    if (!store.state.isAuth) {
        return redirect(app.i18n.localePath('/auth'))
    }
}
```

where if the user is *not* authenticated, they're redirected to the authentication page, located at `/auth`. However, this is a multilingual site, so I need to generate the path corresponding to the current locale. Normally I'd do this using `$i18n.localePath` or in this case, using Nuxt's [context](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/context-helpers/), `app.i18n.localePath()`, however I get this error:

```
 app.i18n.localePath is not a function
```

and I'm not sure why, given that there's a context, and `console.log(app.i18n)` shows me that app.i18n.localePath *is* a function:

```
...
localePath: [Function: bound ],
...
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for some reason localePath does not work in middleware.
You probably should detect current locale manualy.

```js
let locale = app.i18n.locale === app.i18n.defaultLocale ? '' : '/' + app.i18n.locale;

return redirect( locale + '/auth' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `app.localePath('/auth')` instead

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.